# How to Setup Azure File Sync for a VM without internet connectivity

Tags: azure, file, azure-file-share

I'm trying to build a POC for a solution to synchronize files between an Azure File Share using Azure File Sync and a VM that runs on-prem and does not have access to the internet.
I started following the [Azure guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal%2Cproactive-portal) however, when I get to the Server Registration part, I'm blocked since my VM does not have access to the internet, I cannot connect to Azure, but I still need to be able to somehow configure the server endpoint.

[image]

What I already tried:

- Tried to setup the registration like in the documentation but it failed (obviously)
- Tried to search for a "Download agent" option in the Azure portal, that supposedly downloads a registration file (JSON) that I could copy to the VM, but I cannot find the "Download Agent" option anywhere, the only thing I can download is Azure File Sync Agent which is just the installer, that I could copy to the VM without issues to install the Azure File Sync Agent which is a mandatory part in the beginning of the Azure tutorial.

I'm planning on using private link for the actual use of Azure File Sync, but this step to register the server seems to be mandatory.
Are there any other solutions or could it be that I'm somehow understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error  like below:***

[image]

Created virtual machine with ***windows server 2019 Data center*** and storage account with file share like below:

[image]

And ***Deploy Azure file sync*** and ***Sync group*** like below:

[image]

In regsistered server downloaded the Azure file sync agent I selected 2019 as windows server.

[image]

To resolve the error check the below:

***Go to Azure active directory -> users -> select user -> Assigned roles -> Add assignments -> add Application adminsitrator like below:***

[image]

In subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> add contibutor role to the user like below:

[image]

Then click on ***signin*** ->***Internet explorer will be open*** -> click on ***Add***

[image]

In trusted sited click on Add like below:

Internet explorer normally pop up and allow you to add traffic to tranfer sites.

[image]

On scriptError -> click yes  and signin again

***When I try to sign-in again to Azure file sync-server registration, sign-in  is successfully like below:***

[image]

[image]